# Do it while you can or "Strike while the iron is hot" in Chinese

Tags: translation, proverb

How to correctly communicate or express these timely sayings in Chinese? "Do something while the conditions are right" or "Seize the opportunity when it presents itself"

Would this be correct -- 尽你所能

Answer (score 3):

“Strike while the iron is hot” in Chinese is [打鐵趁熱](https://pedia.cloud.edu.tw/Entry/Detail/?title=%E6%89%93%E9%90%B5%E8%B6%81%E7%86%B1)

> 鍛造鐵器必須在加熱鎔燒時進行。比喻做事必須把握時機、不要拖延。

> Forging ironware must be done while the iron is hot. It is a metaphor that you must seize the opportunity to do things without delay.

"Do it while you can" could mean '[機不可失](https://pedia.cloud.edu.tw/Entry/Detail?title=%E6%A9%9F%E4%B8%8D%E5%8F%AF%E5%A4%B1)' (chance is rare, so don't miss it) or [勿失良機](https://pedia.cloud.edu.tw/Entry/Detail?title=%E5%8B%BF%E5%A4%B1%E8%89%AF%E6%A9%9F) (don't miss a good chance)

Comment: Some more: 相机而动，当机立断

Comment: 相机而动 means ' wait your chance' (don't do it until you have the chance to);  We Cantonese have a saying: "蘇州過後冇艇搭 (When a chance is gone, it is gone).